# How can I determine why a PHP 'Exception' is suddenly of type 'Error' instead?

Tags: php

I don't know PHP.  I have some PHP code written about 15 years ago by someone other than me.  It has suddenly started throwing a fatal error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to ReportException() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given
```

The stack trace shows a function `ReportException()` that takes an Exception:

```
function ReportException( Exception $e ) {
    ...
}
```

This function is called by another function `ExceptionHandler()` that takes an argument with no declared type, but which is presumed to be an Exception:

```
function ExceptionHandler( $e ) {

    ReportException( $e );
    ...
}
```

The problem is, no other line in the code base calls `ExceptionHandler()`, so I can't trace where `$e` is being passed from to see why it's now an Error type instead of an Exception type.

There is this:

```
/**
 * Install an exception handler.
 */
function InstallExceptionHandler() {
    set_exception_handler( 'ExceptionHandler' );
}
```

which, when called (which it is), seems to set the `ExceptionHandler()` function as a general sort of Exception Handler.  Not knowing PHP, though, I don't know how to follow this up further.

How can I determine why `$e` is coming to `ExceptionHandler()` as an Error instead of an Exception?  I'm especially interested in answers that can suggest a testable theory about why this is suddenly an issue after the program has worked just fine for ~15 years.  It's currently running on PHP 7.4.3, but I don't know what version it was written for.

**Update**

Barmar and Sammitch's suggestion to change the type of `$e` from `Exception` to `Throwable` causes the Fatal Error not to appear anymore.  However, the app still does not work, so I can't say for certain that that's a full solution yet.  I'll update when I know more.

**Update 2**

The app suddenly started working again, and with no fatal error.  Ready to accept an answer.

Comment: See [Changes to error and exception handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.error-handling) in the PHP 7.0 changes.

Comment: As Barmar noted, PHP7 introduced throwable Errors that are not descended from Exceptions. `function ReportException( Throwable $e ) { ... }` should fix it.

Comment: Try also : *function ExceptionHandler( Throwable $e ) {* with Sammitch changes.

Comment: The app now works after making this change.  If one of you wants to write this up as a complete answer, I'll accept it.